# Nativescript can't get android notification action working

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I'm trying to create a notification with an action, but I can not translate this line of code to Javascript:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
```

From https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Can anyone help? Or has a functional Example?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**It works!**

```
var app = require('application');

var packageName = app.android.context.getPackageName();
var launchIntent = app.android.context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
var className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
var tns = className + '.class';

var intent = new android.content.Intent(app.android.context, eval(tns));

var pIntent = android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(app.android.context, 0, intent, 0);

var resImg = app.android.context.getResources().getIdentifier('icon' , 'drawable', app.android.context.getPackageName());

var mBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(app.android.context);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(resImg);
mBuilder.setContentTitle('My notification');
mBuilder.setContentText('Hello World!');
mBuilder.addAction(resImg, 'see', pIntent);

var mNotificationId = 001;
var sytemservice = app.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
sytemservice.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Tested with emulator android 4.2.2